# can't compare datetime.datetime to unicode

Tags: python, django, datetime

I need to compare my input time with current time. If my input time is older than 5 days, I will do `d = X_value`. Otherwise, `d = Y_value`. The format of my input time like this:

```
my_input__time: 2017-07-05 22:52:00+00:00
```

my view.py looks like this:

```
import datetime
   five_days_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(5)

   if my_input_time < five_days_ago:
         d = X_value
   else:
         d = Y_value
```

I am getting TypeError:can't compare datetime.datetime to unicode. How do I convert `my_input_tine` and `five_dys_ago` into same format so I can compare?

Comment: Where is your input time coming from? You need to convert it to a `datetime` object.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this and tell me

```
import datetime
five_days_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(5)


my_input_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_input__time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+00:00')

   if my_input_time < five_days_ago:
         d = X_value
   else:
         d = Y_value
```

Comment: Thanks @Mauricio! However, I am still getting same error. The format of 2 time value look like this now:

Comment: Thanks @Mauricio! However, I am still getting same error. The format of 2 time value look like this now: my_input__time: 2017-07-05 22:52:00+00:00 five_days_ago: 2017-07-09 21:13:28.967405+00:00. So maybe because of m-seconds in five_days_ago format causes the problem? How can I get rid of ms in five_days_ago?

Answer (score 1):

datetime.now() will return the date down to seconds.

So to add to @thaavik 's answer you could do something like this to compare more accurately:

```
datetime.strptime(my_input_time, '%Y%m%d %h:%m:%s')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

```
from datetime import datetime
t = datetime.strptime(my_input_time, '%Y%m%d') # or whatever your datetime format is
```

you can also make setting `d` more concise:
`d = X_value if t < five_days_ago else Y_value`